# MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out at Timeout._onTimeout

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, timeout

Error

```sh
MongoServerSelectionError: connection timed out
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\NodeJS\SearchEngine\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

Code

```js
try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(connection.url, usermail.config_connection)
    var header = [];
    const db = client.db(connection.name);
    console.log(header_data.return_call_back_header(header_data.header_id_info.ecommerce));
    // res.render('index.ejs', { title: header });
    console.log(header);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
}
```

Config connection

```js
const config_connection = {
    connectTimeoutMS: 5000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 5000,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
}
```

URL

```
url:'mongodb://localhost:27017/searchEngine', name:'searchEngine',
```

Comment: Does anything change if you remove `serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000` ?

Comment: it gives limitation to the server how long you can load data. else it takes to much time to connect and show the same error after 3 min. I take this reference from MongoDB documentation